# RecyclerView, each items has its own activity

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView`, it has `items` in it. I need each `item` to have its own `Activity`, that is, we have `item1` by clicking on it, `Activity1` opens, there is also `item2` about clicking on it, `Activity2` is opened. Can this be done somehow? If so, how? I managed to make it so that when I clicked, the same `Fragment` opened, and the text changes depending on which `item` was clicked. But it doesn't quite suit me.

`Fragment` where the `RecyclerView` is located

```
public class FragmentAttractionRecyclerView extends Fragment {
    
    private RecyclerView mRec;
    private AttractionsAdapter adapter;
    private ArrayList<AttractionsItem> exampleList;
    
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_attraction_test_2, container, false);

    }

    @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull final View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        createExampleList();
        buildRecyclerView();
    }

    public void createExampleList() {
        exampleList = new ArrayList<>();
        exampleList.add(new AttractionsItem(R.mipmap.unnamed, R.drawable.ic_kid, "Baby островок", "Детский", "60₽","Максимальное кол-во детей","10","Возраст","С 1-го до 6 лет"));
        exampleList.add(new AttractionsItem(R.mipmap.unnamed, R.drawable.ic_kid, "Виражи", "Детский", "80₽","Максимальное кол-во пассажиров","24", "Возраст","От 4-х до 12 лет"));
        exampleList.add(new AttractionsItem(R.mipmap.unnamed, R.drawable.ic_kid, "Вокруг света", "Детский", "50₽","Максимальное кол-во пассажиров","12","Возраст","От 3-х до 12 лет"));
        exampleList.add(new AttractionsItem(R.mipmap.unnamed, R.drawable.ic_interactive, "5D кинотеатр", "Интерактивный", "120₽","Максимальное кол-во пассажиров","","Возраст","С 6 лет"));
   }

    public void buildRecyclerView() {
        mRec = requireView().findViewById(R.id.attraction_recycler);
        adapter = new AttractionsAdapter(exampleList);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        mRec.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mRec.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

`Adapter` for `RecyclerView`

```
public class AttractionsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AttractionsAdapter.AttractionsViewHolder> {
    public ArrayList<AttractionsItem> mFavList;

    public AttractionsAdapter(ArrayList<AttractionsItem> favList) {
        mFavList = favList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public AttractionsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_attraction, parent, false);
        AttractionsViewHolder evh = new AttractionsViewHolder(v);
        return evh;

    }

    public static class AttractionsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView card_image_1, card_image_2;
        public TextView card_text_1, card_text_2, card_text_3,attraction_menu_1_1,attraction_menu_1_2;
        public CardView Card;

        public AttractionsViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            card_image_1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_image_1);
            card_image_2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_image_2);
            card_text_1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_text_1);
            card_text_2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_text_2);
            card_text_3 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_text_3);
            attraction_menu_1_1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.attraction_menu_1_1);
            attraction_menu_1_2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.attraction_menu_1_2);
            Card = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Card);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(AttractionsViewHolder holder, int position) {
        AttractionsItem currentItem = mFavList.get(position);
        holder.card_image_1.setImageResource(currentItem.getImg1());
        holder.card_image_2.setImageResource(currentItem.getImg2());
        holder.card_text_1.setText(currentItem.get_attraction_name());
        holder.card_text_2.setText(currentItem.get_attraction_type());
        holder.card_text_3.setText(currentItem.get_attraction_cost());



        holder.Card.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            FragmentBlancAttraction fragment = new FragmentBlancAttraction(); // you fragment
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((FragmentActivity) v.getContext()).getSupportFragmentManager(); // instantiate your view context
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("name", currentItem.get_attraction_name());
            bundle.putString("menu_1_1", currentItem.get_attraction_menu_1_1());
            bundle.putString("menu_1_2", currentItem.get_attraction_menu_1_2());
            bundle.putString("menu_2_1", currentItem.get_attraction_menu_2_1());
            bundle.putString("menu_2_2", currentItem.get_attraction_menu_2_2());
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.nav_default_enter_anim, R.animator.nav_default_exit_anim,
                    R.animator.nav_default_pop_enter_anim, R.animator.nav_default_pop_exit_anim);
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment, fragment);// your container and your fragment
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("tag");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        });


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mFavList.size();
    }
}
```

```
public class AttractionsItem
{
    private int mImg_1,mImg_2;
    private final String mText_attraction_name;
    private final String mText_attraction_type;
    private final String mText_attraction_cost;
    private final String mText_attraction_menu_1_1;
    private final String mText_attraction_menu_1_2;
    private final String mText_attraction_menu_2_1;
    private final String mText_attraction_menu_2_2;
    public AttractionsItem(int img1,int img2, String text_attraction_name, String text_attraction_type, String text_attraction_cost, String text_attraction_menu_1_1, String text_attraction_menu_1_2, String text_attraction_menu_2_1, String text_attraction_menu_2_2)
    {
        mImg_1 = img1;
        mImg_2 = img2;

        mText_attraction_name = text_attraction_name;
        mText_attraction_type = text_attraction_type;
        mText_attraction_cost = text_attraction_cost;
        mText_attraction_menu_1_1 = text_attraction_menu_1_1;
        mText_attraction_menu_1_2 = text_attraction_menu_1_2;
        mText_attraction_menu_2_1 = text_attraction_menu_2_1;
        mText_attraction_menu_2_2 = text_attraction_menu_2_2;
    }
    public int getImg1()
    {
        return mImg_1;
    }
    public int getImg2()
    {
        return mImg_2;
    }
    public String get_attraction_name()
    {
        return mText_attraction_name;
    }
    public String get_attraction_type()
    {
        return mText_attraction_type;
    }
    public String get_attraction_cost()
    {
        return mText_attraction_cost;
    }
    public String get_attraction_menu_1_1()
    {
        return mText_attraction_menu_1_1;
    }
    public String get_attraction_menu_1_2()
    {
        return mText_attraction_menu_1_2;
    }
    public String get_attraction_menu_2_1()
    {
        return mText_attraction_menu_2_1;
    }
    public String get_attraction_menu_2_2()
    {
        return mText_attraction_menu_2_2;
    }
}
```

Comment: `Can this be done somehow? If so, how?` yes, it can be done. add callbacks to every item and handle the callbacks as they are invoked

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RecyclerView onClick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471109/recyclerview-onclick)

Answer (score 0):

The `positon` param inside `onBindViewHolder()` method tells you which item of your `RecyclerView` clicked.
Use this to control your program and in out of `onBindViewHolder()` method you can get your item `position` by `getAdapterPosition()`.

```
holder.Card.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0: {
                // Start first activity.
                break;
            }
            case 1: {
                // Start Second activity.
                break;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: It worked, but when sorting `items`, the `position` does not change, can I somehow bind `onClick` to the `item` `position`?

Comment: You can add a variable to your `AttractionsItem` model class and set the value to your object of it before adding them to your `exampleList`, so handle them into `setOnClickListener` by our new variable of `AttractionsItem` model.

Comment: How to write the code for such an action correctly? Could you please help me with the correct spelling? I just don't quite understand how to do this.